# How Often Can A Function Break Essential Continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, piecewise-continuity

In the context of measurable functions from the reals to the reals:

Let's say a function is essentially continuous at a domain point $c$ iff

$$\exists L, \forall \epsilon, \exists \delta, B_\delta (c) \subseteq \textrm{Cl}(f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(L)))$$

Meaning that there exists some point in the codomain such that the closure of the inverse image of any open ball around that point is a superset of an open ball around the domain point, $c$.

Which means it breaks essential continuity if:

$$\forall L, \exists \epsilon, \forall \delta, B_\delta (c) \nsubseteq  \textrm{Cl}(f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(L)))$$

I'm wondering about the size of this set of discontinuities. I'm pretty sure it can at least be countable. But I'm wondering if it can be uncountable or have Lebesgue Measure $> 0$.

Comment: Characteristic function of a fat Cantor set?

Comment: What is $B(L)$? I assume $B_{\delta}(c)$ is the open ball (open interval? -- would help to state domain and co-domain for $f)$ with center $c$ and radius $\delta.$ Is there a more commonly used term (or description) of "essentially continuous" for those who might be able to help but don't feel up to trying to de-symbolize this?

Comment: I had never seen the fat Cantor set... I'll have to think about that. Very helpful!

Comment: And Dave - sorry - I tried to write it succinctly and clearly, but it seems like I missed the mark. I just rewrote it a bit and I think this is a little more clear. And I agree with you -- I wish there was a more commonly used term, but I haven't found one. The closest thing I have found is "almost continuous", which is fairly Googlable, and that is where I adopted this definition. I adopted the name from "essential supremum", which seems similar.  The domain and codomain are the reals, which I had written on the first line, but maybe that was easy to miss or maybe that's not right. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I completely overlooked that first line. Sorry.